# merge dictionaries in list if same value in python

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries as shown below.

```py
[{'id': 2201187803, 'wind': 0, 'nstid': 294269, 'amrcd': 1, 'insno': '10 Yr Fix', 'fileid': 2007498393, 'arstnme': 'Andy', 'amcd': 1, 'atlstnme': 'America'},
{ 'id': 2201187803, 'wind': 0, 'nstid': 294269, 'amrcd': 1, 'insno': '10 Yr Fix', 'fileid': 2007498393, 'arstnme': 'Amy', 'amcd': 1, 'atlstnme': 'America'}]
```

my output JSON should look like since field `id` is common has value JSON should be appended together

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python 3.x reference below code.

```
ds = [d1, d2]
d = {}
for k in d1.keys():
   d[k] = tuple(d[k] for d in ds)
```